# Canvas Drawing Small Text

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I am trying to draw text on bitmap but text size differs in different pictures. Text size keeps is too small on some bitmaps and large on some. I have noticed that it is small on big resolution  bitmaps.
This is how I'm trying to draw. Please tell what I'm doing wrong

```
val originalBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
        context.contentResolver,
        uri
    )
    val bitmap = convertToMutable(
        originalBitmap
    )
    val ratio = originalBitmap.width/bitmap.width
    val scale = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    val textPaint = TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    textPaint.color = Color.WHITE
    textPaint.textSize = 7f * scale
    textPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL

    val locBound = Rect()
    textPaint.getTextBounds(location,0,location.length,locBound)

    val txtWidth = (canvas.width - 15)
    val txtHeight = textPaint.measureText("yY")

    val txtTopX = ((bitmap.width - txtWidth) - 15).toFloat()
    val txtTopY = ((bitmap.height - txtHeight) - 20).toFloat()

    canvas.drawMultilineText(
        location,
        textPaint,
        txtWidth,
        txtTopX,
        txtTopY,
        0,
        location.length,
        Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE
    )`
fun Canvas.drawMultilineText(
    text: CharSequence,
    textPaint: TextPaint,
    width: Int,
    x: Float,
    y: Float,
    start: Int = 0,
    end: Int = text.length,
    alignment: Layout.Alignment = Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
    spacingMult: Float = 1f,
    spacingAdd: Float = 0f,
    includePad: Boolean = true,
    ellipsizedWidth: Int = width,
    ellipsize: TextUtils.TruncateAt? = null
) {

    val cacheKey = "$text-$start-$end-$textPaint-$width-$alignment-" +
            "$spacingMult-$spacingAdd-$includePad-$ellipsizedWidth-$ellipsize"

    // The public constructor was deprecated in API level 28,
    // but the builder is only available from API level 23 onwards
    val staticLayout =
        StaticLayoutCache[cacheKey] ?: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(text, start, end, textPaint, width)
                .setAlignment(alignment)
                .setLineSpacing(spacingAdd, spacingMult)
                .setIncludePad(includePad)
                .setEllipsizedWidth(ellipsizedWidth)
                .setEllipsize(ellipsize)
                .build()
        } else {
            StaticLayout(
                text, start, end, textPaint, width, alignment,
                spacingMult, spacingAdd, includePad, ellipsize, ellipsizedWidth
            )
                .apply { StaticLayoutCache[cacheKey] = this }
        }

    staticLayout.draw(this, x, y)
}
```

Here is the result I'm getting
[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1cva.jpg)  [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDCyG.jpg) [Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT0Mw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can set font size based on your image size. for example your font size can be 0.03 of image size. So in this way your font size on image can be change base on your image size. so you need to do this as bellow:

```
var imageSize = max(originalBitmap.width, originalBitmap.height)
var fontScale = 0.03
var textSize = imageSize * fontScale  
textPaint.textSize = textSize
```

You must note that image can be landscape or portrait. so we get width or height that is greater as `imageSize`. You can change `fontScale` according to your needs.

Also, I think there is no need to use scale variable in `textSize` computing. because it is a display metric and can be different in various devices, so must not be affected in bitmap text size, and text size must only define based on bitmap image size.

Comment: Not working. Now it is big for large images

Comment: I edited my answer. Please give it a try. this solution worked for me.